# Using ServiceBus as out parameter in C# Script Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure

I want to have an azure function written in C# Script which is triggered by http request and then is sending message to Azure ServiceBus Topic. All works well when out parameter is set to string, but I want to be able to set metadata of message such as To when sending message.
I suppose I should change string type to Message (from ServiceBus) to achieve that but I don't know how to include that package.
My code function.json:

```
    {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "connection": "AzureServiceBus",
      "name": "outputSbMsg",
      "topicName": "producttest",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "serviceBus"
    }
  ]
}
```

and function definition:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;  
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;  

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ICollector<Message> outputSbMsg, ILogger log)
```

I have an error: The type or namespace name 'Message' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
and I cannot find the right include and #r combination to make it work

Comment: general comment: do yourself a favor and do not use C# script but write and compile your Function in proper C#. Sooner or later almost everybody gets there anyway and you make your life a lot easier

Comment: @silent That's true. I can do it in c# - simple & straight forward (Visual Studio Code & deploy to Azure Functions) but for that one I have a requirement to do it as C# script and sadly it's much different and after googling all the internet (I have such feeling) I have no solution

Answer (score 0):

Add `using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that but I'm getting message that there is no metadata for such package. I have extensions installed (function version 3)